# Is there a clever way to get hold of all the CSS rules that is not supported by IE9 compared to IE10+?

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

Our product needs to support IE9, but we have a history of assuming that IE10+ CSS rules are supported in IE9.

Is there a clever way to get hold of all the CSS rules that works in IE10+ but is not supported in IE9, with the intention to use that data in static code analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complete list of properties and their compatibility from IE6 to IE10 can be found [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: So I guess the next step is to crawl that page and create a diff between IE9 and IE10 per rule

Comment: Btw, do you know why IE11 isnt there?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. I could not find anything on their page on CSS compatibility changes in IE11. Just a bunch of IE-specific javascript functions that were removed, the "MSIE" part being removed from the user agent and all that jazz.